# How do I insert an image into a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
public void InsertAnImage(Guid i)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("");

    Stream stream = FileUpload1.FileContent;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

    string myConnectionString = AllQuestionsPresented.connectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(AllQuestionsPresented.connectionString))
    {
        // sample query with parameters to insert into db
        string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO [UserProfile] (UserID, Picture) Values (@userId, @picture)";
        // conn is your db connection
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
        // creating parameters
        SqlParameter paramId = new SqlParameter("@userId", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
        paramId.Value = 45;
        // you picture parameter, and assigning its the value
        SqlParameter paramPicture = new SqlParameter("@picture", SqlDbType.Binary, myImage.Length);// red line here
        paramPicture.Value = myImage;// red line here
        // adding params to command
        command.Parameters.Add(paramId);
        command.Parameters.Add(paramPicture);
        // then execute your command
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

How do I put a streamreader instead of Filestream reader to the database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload images to SQL Server 2005 using ASP.Net MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479699/upload-images-to-sql-server-2005-using-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I have already answered the same question on Stack Overflow, here: - [how to store images in sql server?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449042/how-to-store-images-in-sql-server/6449200#6449200

Comment: Refer below link: http://www.redmondpie.com/inserting-in-and-retrieving-image-from-sql-server-database-using-c/

Comment: Doing this is rarely a good idea.

I would nearly always recommend storing the files on the file system and storing the path in the database. This stops your database from getting too big too quickly making backup, restore, replication etc all easier to do.

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne - Good point - changed to a comment.

Comment: I updated my question. Please look above

Comment: @David, But i am not sure about the filesystem permissions of the host :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another article:

[Save and Retrieve Images from the Database using ASP.NET 2.0 and ASP.NET 3.5](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=129)

However, the general consensus is that it's better to store the image in the file system.

Comment: How do I store an image on a hosts file system? Will he even allow me?

Comment: I don't know who 'he' is.  Your application should have write access to sub-directories in your hosting environment.