# Insert and return images from a SQL Server database 

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I am attempting to insert images into a SQL Server database using ASP.NET MVC3 and C#.

Is there a good tutorial or answer someone could give me here? I am looking for such things as what the controller, model and view would look like!

Thanks!

Comment: I think this would work for you:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479699/upload-images-to-sql-server-2005-using-asp-net-mvc Here is also a really comprehensive article on storing and retrieving images using SQL and MVC: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/streamingblobhttp.aspx

Answer (score 0):

here is how to do that : [Storing and Retrieving Images from SQL Server Using Strored Procedures and C#.net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/354639/Storing-and-Retrieving-Images-from-SQL-Server-Usin)